# Differential equation for a matrix-valued function

Tags: matrices, derivatives

Let $Y\left(t\right)$ be a matrix function, then does $\frac{d}{dt}Y^{T}Y=O$
necessarily imply $Y^{T}\left(t\right)Y\left(t\right)\equiv I$ ? Why or why not?
Here $Y^{T}$ the transpose of $Y$ , $O$ zero matrix and $I$ the
identity matrix.

Comment: What did you learn? What have you tried?

Comment: Have you tried a 2 by 2 case to see what may happen?

Comment: Do you have any kind of initial condition?  Otherwise the answer is trivially no:  If $X$ is any matrix with the property that $X^tX\neq I$, then setting $Y(t) = X$ (constant matrix) gives a "no" answer.

Comment: @Jack Let's exclude the trivial case when $Y\left(t\right)=$const. 

At first sight, it appears that $Y^{T}Y$ can be any constant matrix,
but what I am hoping is that somebody can give me a proof that this
is not the case, that the only choice is the identity matrix. I konw
there is something special about $Y^{T}Y$, such as symmetric, so
definitely not any constant matrix !

Answer (score 1):

The correct conclusion from $\frac{d}{dt}(\text{something})=0$ is that $\text{(something)}$ does not depend on $t$. This is all one can get, because any function independent of $t$ has zero derivative with respect to $t$.

But if it is also known that $Y(t_0)$ is orthogonal for some $t_0$, then  from $Y^T(t_0)Y(t_0)=I$ it indeed follows that $Y^TY\equiv I$.